# SSH, его логи и актуальные настройки 2017

Tags: linux, ssh, логирование, sshfs, openssh

Уважаемые форумчане! Требуется ваша помощь!

Разбираюсь с технологией **SSH(2)**, есть несколько вопросов:

- Какие **актуальные поправки в настройках** клиента и сервера на 2017 год?

*(Например слышал что уже md5 не безопасно, может ещё что-то есть и я не знаю)*

- Чем **смотреть и изучать логи**?

*(Хотелось бы конечно **с подсветкой и в реальном времени**, ну и с GUI, хотя и без него тоже пойдёт. Что-нибудь с минимумом зависимостей)*

- Как заставить **логи** писать **в отдельный журнал**, а не в системный?

*(Чтобы все логи связанные с SSH были в другой директории, хотя бы временно, для изучения технологии)*

- На что обратить внимание при анализе лога?

*(Какие признаки попыток вторжения, кроме многих попыток ввода пароля)*

- Как пробиться по такой схеме:

**Хост1** == **Роутер (NAT0)** == **Провайдер-NAT1** == **Интернет** == **Провайдер-NAT2** == **Хост2**
Что посоветуете в этой ситуации?

- Какой **сервер** и **клиент** посоветуете?

*(Выбор я уже сделал, но вдруг удивите :))*

Мне по сути от SSH нужны прежде всего **операции с файлами**
(подмонтировал и в файловом менеджере перемещаешь/копируешь/удаляешь файлы и директории)

Comment: с прошлого сезона ничего не поменялось.

Comment: При чем тут "актуальные поправки в настройках" и алгоритм хеширования ?

Comment: @matz, а что именно Вас удивило? Выбор алгоритма хэширования разве нет в настройках? Актуальные - это имеется ввиду с учётом последних тенденций, всё меняется со временем, разве нет?

Comment: Хауту по настройке сервера вот тут очень хорошее: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ssh . Для блокировки от c001][akiroff я бы ещё добавил fail2ban. Сервер и клиент - ванильный.

Comment: @donRumata, это я уже читал, все настройки переписал, каждую из них попытался понять

Comment: Ну, описанного там - вполне достаточно. Вырубай вход по паролю, оставляй по ключу и всё.

Comment: @donRumata, хорошо, спасибо, просто все эти статьи которые я читал давно опубликованы, может думал что-нибудь поменялось за это время, ведь время не стоит на месте

Comment: Учитывая, что там вики - можно посмотреть время последней правки. А так - нет, кардинально ничего нового. Разве что на ssh v1 все наконец-то окончательно забили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Касательно вопросов о логах постараюсь ответить.

В разных дистрибутивах Linux логи пишутся в разные файлы. Начинается всё с */var/log* а дальше возможны варианты. Предположим, что у Вас лог пишется в */var/log/messages*. Тогда смотреть сообщения по мере их появления можно так:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages &
```

Если Вас интересуют тоько сообщения, касающиеся *ssh*, то можно модифицировать так:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep ssh &
```

Если есть желание сохранить лог в отдельном файле, то можно так:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep ssh > ~/my_log.txt &
```

Ну и последнее: в большинстве дистрибутивов, системные логи может смотреть только root. Как получить полномочия root - завистит от  ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендации всё те же: отключите вход с паролем и не ходите сами.

Для этого надо в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` дописать:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```